# increment an attribute id in different loops but the id has to be unique in XSLT

Tags: attributes, xslt-1.0, increment

My question is about how to increment an attribute id in different loops but the id has to be unique in XSLT?

Comment: Where is your XSLT? What Issue you exactly face.

Comment: <xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:for-each select="PFA/Records/Person">
        <Entity>
          <xsl:attribute name="ID">
</Entity>
</xsl:for-each>

<xsl:for-each select="PFA/Records/Entity">
        <Entity>
          <xsl:attribute name="ID">
</Entity>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

Comment: I require the id to be incremented in a global way between the 2 for loops @Rupesh

Comment: Show your input and desired output

Comment: Desired Output is:
<Entity ID="1">
  <Type>Individual</Type> 
  <Gender>Male</Gender>
  <First_Name>Nourirtg</First_Name> 
</Entity>
<Entity ID="2">
  <Type>Individual</Type> 
  <Gender>Male</Gender>
  <First_Name>Masain</First_Name> 
</Entity>
<Entity ID="3">
  <Type>Individual</Type> 
  <Gender>Male</Gender>
  <First_Name>Chinmai</First_Name> 
</Entity>
<Entity ID="4">
  <Type>Business</Type> 
  <Full_Name>Sberbank Factoring</Full_Name> 
</Entity>
<Entity ID="5">
  <Type>Business</Type> 
  <Full_Name>Helab Factoring</Full_Name> 
</Entity>

Comment: and input @nandhini

Comment: <Records>
    <Person id="196542" action="add" date="19-Jul-2017">
      <NameDetails>
        <Name NameType="Primary Name">
          <NameValue>
   <FirstName>Nourirtg</FirstName>
           </NameValue>
        </Name>
  </NameDetails>
  </Person>
  <Entity id="11051064" action="add" date="05-May-2017">
      <NameDetails>
        <Name NameType="Primary Name">
          <NameValue>
   <EntityName>Association Rahma de Torcy Marne-la-Vallée</EntityName>
   </NameValue>
        </Name>
   </NameDetails>
   </Entity>
</Records>

Comment: this is the input @Rupesh

Answer (score 0):

For your current requirement you can handle this simply like this

```
    <xsl:template match="Records">
    <xsl:for-each select="//Person|//Entity">
        <Entity>
            <xsl:attribute name="ID" select="position()"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="self::Person">
                    <Type>Individual</Type>
                    <Gender>Male</Gender>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="descendant::FirstName"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <Type>Business</Type>
                    <Full_Name><xsl:value-of select="descendant::EntityName"/></Full_Name>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </Entity>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks @Rupesh... One More doubt. Since I am new to XSLT I am not sure of many things.

Comment: Is it possible to remove duplicates from a tag?

Comment: Yes @nandhinisuresh

Comment: <Reason_Listed>Special Interest Person (SIP);Sanctions Lists;Special Interest Person (SIP);Bank;</Reason_Listed>

Comment: If so my output looks lik above tag. Is it possible to remove duplicates?if so how can I do it?@Rupesh

Comment: My Input looks like this

Comment: <Description1List>
  <Description1Name Description1Id="1" RecordType="Person">Politically Exposed Person (PEP)</Description1Name> 
  <Description1Name Description1Id="2" RecordType="Person">Relative or Close Associate (RCA)</Description1Name> 
- </Description1List>
- <Description2List>

Comment: <Description2Name Description2Id="1" Description1Id="3">Sanctions Lists</Description2Name> 
  <Description2Name Description2Id="2" Description1Id="3">Other Official Lists</Description2Name> 
  </Description2List>
- <Description3List>
  <Description3Name Description3Id="1" Description2Id="3">Ship</Description3Name> 
  <Description3Name Description3Id="2" Description2Id="3">Company</Description3Name> 
 </Description3List>

Comment: Inside person and entity the description will be as:

Comment: <Descriptions>
  <Description Description1="1" /> 
  <Description Description1="3" Description2="1" /> 
  <Description Description1="2" Description2="3" Description3="3" /> 
  </Descriptions>

Comment: so we have to have the code as(1,2,3) and get details from the above descriptionlist specified

Comment: why not you edit your question rather than paste it in comment. @nandhinisuresh

Comment: it actually has a limit of characters tats why.. is it difficult to understand the way I pasted.@Rupesh

Comment: when I try editing the question it shows an error stating it does not require the specified format. I am trying to change the format but stil it shows the same@Rupesh

Comment: Try to put a new question on stack, because in above format i am not able to understand what your need. @nandhinisuresh

Comment: Hi @Rupesh I have asked the issue as another question. Can you help me with it.